# bcryptjs: Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, number

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, bcrypt

My goal is to put a login and register form on one page. The register already works but I always get this error when logging in.

I have already tried several things and believe that it has something to do with the submit button. because when the login button is pressed, the login function is not even called. Or I think that I have somehow set the routes wrong.

Here is the html code (register.hbs):

```
 <div class="main_content transform8">
    <img class="swipe transform" src="img/ETCO-img/swipepattern.svg" height="150%" width="auto">


    <img class="secwave transform7" style="filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0,0, 0.171));"
        src="img/ETCO-img/secwave.svg" height="30%" width="auto">
    <img class="logo transform5" src="img/ETCO-img/logoetco.png" height="270px">
    <img id="wave" class="wave transform6" style="filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.171));"
        src="img/ETCO-img/wave.svg" height="400px" width="auto">

    <div id="login">
        <h1 class="loginh1 transform2">Willkommen</h1>
        <form class="form transform3" action="/auth/register" method="POST">
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="emaillogin"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/mail.svg" height="25px"> <span
                        style="margin-left:25px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="example@gmail.com" class="input" type="email" id="emaillogin" name="emaillogin">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="passwordlogin"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/lock.svg" height="25px"> <span
                        style="margin-left:25px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="Passwort" class="input" type="password" id="passwordlogin" name="passwordlogin">
            </div>
            <button type="SUBMIT" class="bnlogin transform4">LOGIN</button>
        </form>

        
    </div>



    <div class="registerarea transform7">
        <h1 class="registerh1 ">Join us</h1>
        <form class="formregister" action="/auth/register" method="POST">
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="name"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/user.svg" height="30px"> <span
                        style="margin-left:30px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="Your Name" class="input" type="text" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="email"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/mail.svg" height="25px"> <span
                        style="margin-left:25px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="example@gmail.com" class="input" type="email" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="password"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/lock.svg" height="25px"> <span
                        style="margin-left:25px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="Passwort" class="input" type="password" id="password" name="password">
            </div>
            <div class="input-container">
                <label class="label" for="passwordConfirm"><img src="../img/ETCO-img/icons/lock.svg" height="25px">
                    <span style="margin-left:25px;"></span></label>
                <input placeholder="Passwort Bestätigen" class="input" type="password" id="passwordConfirm"
                    name="passwordConfirm">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btnregister">Lets go</button>
        </form>
        {{#if message}}
        <h3 class="alert alert-danger mt-4">{{message}}</h3>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
```

and the routes/auth.js

```
const express = require('express');
const authController = require('../controllers/auth');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/register', authController.register);
router.post('/register', authController.login);

module.exports = router;
```

and the code of the controller auth.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
   host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
   user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
   password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
   database: process.env.DATABASE
});

exports.register = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { name, email, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;
    let hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    console.log(hashedPassword);

db.query('SELECT email from users WHERE email = ?', [email], async(error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    if (results.length > 0) {
        return res.render('message/emailerror');
    } else if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
        return res.render('message/pwderror');
    }

    let hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    console.log(hashedPassword);

    db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', { name: name, email: email, password: hashedPassword }, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
            console.log('+++++++++++   User registered   ++++++++++')
            //route to other page later on
        }
    });

});

}

 //to login the user

 exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    console.log('#####   Login Versuch gestartet  #####');
     try {
        const {emaillogin, passwordlogin} = req.body;
           if(!emaillogin || !passwordlogin) {
           console.log('Fehler Versuch es nochmal');
           return;
        } else{console.log('funktioniert')}

    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

I hope someone can help me here, because unfortunately I haven't had much to do with node.js.

Comment: Not sure any of the front-end code here is relevant at all.

Comment: Are you sure `password` is defined? You might want to add an assertion that `password.length > 8` or something similar.

Comment: How are you calling `await` in a function that's not `async`?

Comment: oh ok ... but yes the password is defined. if not than it would not work for the register?

Comment: unfortunately i haven't really understood the difference and the connection between await and async :/

Comment: `async` functions are those that can employ `await`, and `await` is the point in your code where you "await" the result of some `async` operation.

Comment: oh ok. thanks for your Explanation. So, that means i need both in the login function to work correctly?

Comment: The question of the password being defined hinges on whether you've set up a body parser for url-encoded POST data.

Comment: i think so.. yea

Comment: Can you show the line? Did you `console.log(password)` yet? I mean the error is pretty clear

Comment: Regarding async/await, here's a short primer: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/kpj204wL/

Comment: hmm not yet, i will try the console.log(password) now

Comment: so i tried it now. but i dont get anything back. so where would u place the console.log(password) maybe i put it on the wrong place

Comment: Right after `const { name, email, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;` to see if the form data is actually available

Comment: but this must work because otherwise i cannot register a new user

Comment: "This must work" is the start of enlightenment if you disregard your instinct and go about proving that it actually does work.

Comment: yeaaa you are right :D my bad. I tried it and it works. i get all infos from the form

Comment: The error should point to a line number. Which bcrypt command fails exactly? And why are you hashing twice, once without await?

Comment: nextTick(callback.bind(this, Error("Illegal arguments: "+(typeof s)+', '+(typeof salt))));